# Docstring mismatch using NumPy's vectorize

Tags: python, numpy, python-sphinx

I have a function, which need to be vectorized using NumPy's [vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) factory. As stated in the documentation the docstring is copied, but it seems that `help` and Sphinx aren't using the `__doc__` attribute of the actual object. Most likely it's related to the type of the object returned by `vectorize` which is `numpy.lib.function_base.vectorize` rather than `function`.

Here is an minimal example:

```
import numpy as np

def _f(x):
    """Function to be vectorized"""
    return x**2

f = np.vectorize(_f)  # Will be exported from the module as public API
print f.__doc__       # Prints _f.__doc__
print help(f)         # Prints np.vectorize.__doc__
```

While `__doc__` gives the docstring as defined in function `_f`, `help(f)` displayed the entire documentation of the `vectorize` function. As a result the exported function object `f` and it's documentation aren't picked up by the autodoc extension of Sphinx.

One quick'n'dirty solution which crossed my mind is to wrap the vectorization in another function and define the docstring here. But this seems a little awkward to me:

```
def wrapper(x):
    """Function to be vectorized"""
    tmp = np.vectorize(_f)
    return tmp(x)
```

Does anybody has the same problem and knows a better solution to get autodoc working with `vectorize` functors?

Comment: Stefan, I suggest you bring this up on the [numpy mailing list](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/mailing-lists.html).

Comment: @Jaime As hpaulj pointed out it seems to be more a problem of Python's pydoc functionality rather than NumPy.

Answer (score 3):

`np.vectorize` is actually a class, so `f = np.vectorize(_f)` is a call to its `__init__`, and returns an instance of that class.  When you use `f(abc)`, you are actually invoking its `__call__` method.

`f.__doc__` is the attribute assigned to that instance during creation, either from a parameter you provide or the `_f.__doc__`.

It looks like the `help(f)` (and autodoc?) displays the class `.__doc__`, rather than the instance's own `__doc__`.  `type(f).__doc__`.

This isn't a solution, but it may help point in the right direction.

If I do `np.vectorize.__doc__=f.__doc__`, `help(f)` now displays:

```
Help on vectorize in module numpy.lib.function_base object:

f = class vectorize(builtins.object)
 |  Function to be vectorized
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
 |      Return arrays with the results of `pyfunc` broadcast (vectorized) over
 |      `args` and `kwargs` not in `excluded`.
 ...
```

This displays the assigned `__doc__`, but also shows the class methods.

`np.ufunc` objects show similar behaviour.  Compare `help(np.add)` with `np.add.__doc__`.  One shows the background information for all `ufunc`, the other, the specifics for that object.

In fact `help` for any class object with a `__call__` gives the class `__doc__`.  I wonder if there's a way of tweaking `pydoc.help` so it checks the instance for a `__doc__` before using the class `__doc__`.

Comment: Thanks for the summary. I will definitively look into it.